# How would you make other parameter changes depend on the first parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
const TEMPLATES = {
  emailVerification: getEmailVerificationTemplate,
  welcome: getWelcomeTemplate
}

type TemplateName = "emailVerification" | "welcome"

function getEmailTemplate<T extends TemplateName>(
  templateName: T,
  data?: Parameters<typeof TEMPLATES[T]>
): EmailContent {
  return TEMPLATES[templateName](data)
}

function getEmailVerificationTemplate(
  data: { name: string; tokenLink: string }
): EmailContent {
  //return template
}

function getWelcomeTemplate(): EmailContent {
  //return template
}
```

Above is the function that returns email template based on
TemplateName argument received in the parent function (i.e. getEmailTemplate)

Essentially what I am trying to do is based on templateName that getEmailTemplate receives,
narrow down type of the second parameter, hence I can achieve type safety as well as inference at editor level.

However, this is the compiler error I receive with above code:

```
Argument of type '[data: { name: string; tokenLink: string; }] | [] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; tokenLink: string; }'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; tokenLink: string; }'.ts(2345)
```

Is there any typescript idiomatic way to do this other than using method overloading?